# Build solution and start IIS Express with .bat file (without opening Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, iis-express

For local development purposes, I'd like to just run a .bat file to build my solution and run it on iis express.

Here's what I've got:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat" 
devenv "C:\Path\To\Solution.sln" /build debug
echo "Web build completed. Launching IIS..." 
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\"
iisexpress /path:C:\Path\To\Webroot /port:58389 /clr:v4.0
```

This does indeed successfully build the solution and start iis express.

Here's my output:

```
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.28010.2050.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: PDS.Utilities, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Build started: Project: PDS.Ibex, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
...
========== Build: 11 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
"Web build completed. Launching IIS..."
Copied template config file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS 
Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config' to 'C:\Users\CXSVH9\AppData\Local\Temp\2\iisexpress\applicationhost2018116141435830.config'
Updated configuration file 'C:\Users\CXSVH9\AppData\Local\Temp\2\iisexpress\applicationhost2018116141435830.config' with given cmd line info.
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:58389/" for site "Development Web Site" application "/"
Registration completed
IIS Express is running.
Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express
```

When I fire up `localhost`, I get the following output in Command Prompt:

```
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:58389/login.aspx
Request ended: http://localhost:58389/login.aspx with HTTP status 200.0
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:58389/login.aspx
Request ended: http://localhost:58389/login.aspx with HTTP status 200.0
```

`200`'s. So, that's good.

But in the browser, I get the message: "Requested view is not available" (a message peculiar to my environment, I'd guess — I just started with this codebase).

Of course, if I start the project from inside Visual Studio, everything works fine. But, as a frontend dev, I'd rather skip that and just fire the project up with a script and use VS Code to edit my static files.

Any thoughts on why this is not loading assets from my web project?

The really frustrating thing is I had this working before, but accidentally deleted my original .bat file and can't get things sussed again.

**UPDATE**

When I clear cache in the browser, it does `GET` all my assets with `200`'s. But still, "Requested view is not available."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me somewhat sheepishly answer my own question: I needed to start an additional web service that our website depends upon. This was as simple as writing another batch file to start that web service using the same technique above, but changing the path and the port to their appropriate values.